# Trouble Building Membase

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, membase

On Ubuntu 10.04

command line:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential automake libtool pkg-config check libssl-dev sqlite3 libevent-dev libcurl libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
automake is already the newest version.
libtool is already the newest version.
pkg-config is already the newest version.
E: Couldn't find package libcurl
```

This looked good to me as I already have curl installed so I did this:

```
membase_1.6.0beta4_src$ make
mkdir -p lib
(cd memcached && ./configure --enable-isasl && make)
/bin/sh: ./configure: not found
make: *** [build_configure] Error 127
```

Seeing this error I ran the following under memcached:

```
autoconf
```

Now I get:

```
membase_1.6.0beta4_src$ make
mkdir -p lib
(cd memcached && ./configure --enable-isasl && make)
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
make: *** [build_configure] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Made these modifications:

```
build_configure:
        mkdir -p lib
        (cd memcached && ./config/autorun.sh && ./configure --enable-isasl &&
$(MAKE))
        (cd bucket_engine && ./configure --with-memcached=../memcached && $
(MAKE))
        (cd ep-engine && ./config/autorun.sh && ./configure --with-
memcached=../memcached && $(MAKE))
        (cd libmemcached && ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../lib --disable-
shared --disable-dtrace --enable-static --with-memcached=../memcached/
memcached && $(MAKE) && $(MAKE) install)
        (cd libvbucket && ./config/autorun.sh && ./configure --
prefix=`pwd`/../lib --disable-shared --enable-static && $(MAKE) && $
(MAKE) install)
        (cd vbucketmigrator && ./config/autorun.sh && ./configure --
prefix=`pwd`/../lib --without-sasl --with-isasl --with-memcached=../
memcached && $(MAKE))
        (cd libconflate && ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../lib --disable-shared
--enable-static && $(MAKE) && $(MAKE) install)
        (cd moxi && ./config/autorun.sh && ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../lib
--with-memcached=../memcached/memcached --enable-moxi-libvbucket --
enable-moxi-libmemcached CFLAGS="-I../lib/include -Wno-error"
LDFLAGS="-L../lib/lib" && $(MAKE))
        (cd ns_server && $(MAKE))
```